# How to get mails from my mailbox with no IMAP?

Tags: php, email

Generally, i use php, but any other possibilities. Hope my hosting provider will support it.))

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how/where your mail is stored.

There's:

1. Local unix mbox (previously read)
2. Local unix spool (newly received, not yet read)
3. POP server
4. IMAP server
5. Web-based (hotmail, gmail, yahoo, etc...)
6. Exchange server (yet another protocol)
7. Domino server (yet another other protocol)
8. etc...

Each is accessed differently, so there's no way we can answer your question without more details.

Comment: Then you'd have to use the webmail provider's API, or try to write a screen scraper for each site. Google: http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/   Yahoo: http://developer.yahoo.com/mail/  and so on for each.